# Compare multiple cells from different pages, same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I want to compare some cells from different pages of the same sheet (if name if the same, numbers the same then out SUCCESS else ERROR). "NCO Activity Sheet(DI-MDI)" I started working on the H19 cell, I don't know if the formula is correct or not.

[image: Here]

I basically want to compare every name and number beside it with the table from "Statistics"

[image: Here]

So, B19,C19 compare with Z34,AA34 and the names too.

Here's the sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J3PCDqKi5n39fZ1Ks3LdWDGaJ_o-4t92FVxrJiL8_1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete **H4:H12** and paste this into **H4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(VLOOKUP(A4:A12, {Statistics!S31:S70, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Statistics!T31:X70),,999))}, 2, 0)=
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B4:F12),,999)), "SUCCESS", "ERROR"))
```

[image: 0]